# How to show the ID of array objects?

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering how to print ids of items inside an array.
I have and array called localData, with a list of objects inside. Every object is a mini array of 3 strings.
In my `ng-repeat` when i set `{{items in array}}` it prints the content and not the id. How can i print only ids?

```
localData = {"-KRFLxEmRoS7M9gKDXVE":{"postBody":"1) remove lag 2) add animations",
"postTitle":"Top Title $$$","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRFM6Jm2wQemtl878Ur":"postBody":"Annanana","postTitle":"Ananaj",
"userName":"[Admin]"},"-KRFM7rcEe5K5PXkb29v":{"postBody":"Abshhsua","postTitle":"Ababjsjs","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRFM96LtmaXRTnUXJoV":{"postBody":"Gabshsysus","postTitle":"Bshshshshs","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRFMAnqecr85xUcOCuw":{"postBody":"Sbsbshshsusudu","postTitle":"Ushhshshs","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRFMCkO3JdhA_0MlwwM":{"postBody":"Hshshshs","postTitle":"Sjjsjsjs","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRFMLtDJsO0fGYA9JEO":{"postBody":"Fake",
"postTitle":"OMG EPICCCCCCOOOO","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRFMQBwIbK6s5lVMlbW":{"postBody":"Asdrobololo","postTitle":"Asdrubale","userName":"[Admin]"},
"-KRI7TVGM0U5emvwD0i7":{"postBody":"Htrsdvgh","postTitle":"Uutfcbuj","userName":"[Admin]"},"-KRITPhL8m-qCCO9y4vY":
{"postBody":"Iiiiiiiwwwwww","postTitle":"Jjjdhd","userName":"[Admin]"}}
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: Can you update your local data and what is your expectation.

Comment: My objective is to print only the IDs such as KRFLxEmRoS7M9gKDXVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])

.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope) {
  var object={"nm_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Nome do Question&aacute;rio"},"ds_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o do Question&aacute;rio"},"dt_inicio_vigencia":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Data de Vig&ecirc;ncia"}};
          $scope.items = [];
angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
            $scope.items.push(key);
        }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tryied to implement this code into my project, but when i when i export the index value using {{index}}, it doesen't work

Comment: now try it. It will work.I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: At the moment i have not my pc with me. I will try it tomorrow and i will let you know if it works

Comment: @Davide Nale ya sure.

Comment: @David Nale It's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Store the local data like below to get the id easily. Try this below.

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope) {

var accountservice=[{"id":"1","title":"Savings Account","services":[{"types":"ATM card request"},{"types":"loan request"}]},
    {"id":"2","title":"Current Account","services":[{"types":"cheque book request"},{"types":"ATM card request"}]},
    {"id":"3","title":"Demat Account","services":[{"types":"loan request"},{"types":"ATM card request"}]}];
  
$scope.accountservices =  accountservice;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in accountservices">
   <p>{{value.id}}</p>
   <ul><li ng-repeat="account in value.services">{{account.types}}</li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but the thing is that the data is stored on firebase and generated with a custom id